# Remove auto-completion with Enter key in Kate text editor

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, text-editor, kate

In [Kate text editor](http://kate-editor.org/), one can auto complete using either the Tab or the Enter key.
I find auto-completion with the Enter key disruptive, because often you really do mean what you say, and want to go to a new line.  Who knew.
How can I disable *only* the Enter key auto-completion without removing the Tab auto-completion?

Comment: See https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=218&t=111286 and https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=316413

Comment: @sashoalm My autocompletion works fine.  Its just that I'd like to remove the Enter key binding to do so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You CAN'T do that.

From https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=316413:

> Sorry, but auto-complete really works ok the way it is. If we alter that behavior, we will get many more reports about that than with the current way.

And then:

> You can deactivate the auto completion in the settings. Then you can invoke it manually. If that doesn't help, then yes, Kate is perhaps not the best choice, sorry.

So it seems, from the developers' own mouth, that Enter can't be turned off. You can turn off autocomplete as a whole, or if you don't like that, you can find another text editor. Or you can edit the source code yourself, after all it's Open Source.

The developers like it as it is, and have no intention of making the behavior configurable.

Comment: Bummer.  I really like Kate.  Seems like a simple feature to implement.

Comment: Send a patch, post it on http://reviewboard.kde.org, and we will likely accept it ;)

Answer (score 4):

I've seen a workaround in [this article](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/jxujgr/change_kates_default_key_for_autocompletion/) that works for me:

> go to: Settings->Configure Keyboard Shortcuts. Then change the Action:
> "Insert Smart Newline to Enter instead of Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED 2021 (discovered via the bug here in 2023)**

Goto:

**Settings -> Configure Kate -> Editing -> Auto Completion**

**UNCHECK** "Auto select first completion entry"

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=316413#c10

"Add option to preselect nothing when automatic completion is invoked

Since the first entry was previously always preselected, it sometimes
made entering newlines (with the return key) hard for users who are not
familiar with Shift+Enter."

Answer (score 0):

I am using Kate Version 21.12.3 with "french menu"
I have selected "no auto completion" that way:

```
open a configuration window with  :  CTRL + MAJ + ,   
on the left,  select the third item (modification in french)
then select the fourth item ( complétion automatique in french)
then uncheck "complétion automatique"

click "apply"  and "OK"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).